# Need to use a NSTextView (or NSTextField) for a clickable URL

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview

I'm given an arbitrary NSAttributedString (parsed from markdown, not that it matters here) which may contain URLs that I want to be clickable in a text field within an NSTableView cell. The requirements state that if the user clicks the URL, they be taken to it with the default browser. IF they click anywhere else in the cell, we have default behavior (displaying an additional info popup).

I'm attempting to use a NSTextView to display the content. However, clicking outside the URL but within the view selects the text and eats the mouse click. Making the view not selectable won't allow clicking the URL either. I also don't really want the text to be selectable but that's a minor side problem.

So... I decided to make my view controller an NSTextViewDelegate so I could use some of those callbacks. But my app crashes if I set the NSTextView's delegate property to 'self'. This happens even if I don't implement any of the functions, even though they are all optional.

I'm using Swift 3 and wonder if there's some bug or other issue there? The call stack appears to be sending a `textView:willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRanges:toCharacterRanges:` message even though it's not implemented. And incidentally, implementing that method isn't helping either.

Any help, or sample code in Swift 3 using the delegate protocol, would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the crash I get by simply setting the delegate property on NSTextView:
[image: Crash]

By request, here's the code that set's the delegate. Currently I just set it whenever the message changes. This can obviously be optimized but for now I just want to see it work.

```
var notification: SSNotification! {
    didSet {
        guard let notificationCellView = self.view as? SSNotificationCellView else { return }
        notificationCellView.subjectLabel.stringValue = notification.subject
        if let description = notification.message , description != "" {
            let attrString = TSMarkdownParser.standard().attributedString(fromMarkdown: description)

            notificationCellView.messageLabel.textStorage?.setAttributedString(attrString)
            notificationCellView.messageLabel.isHidden = false
            notificationCellView.messageLabel.delegate = self

        } else {
            notificationCellView.messageLabel.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code added. Nothing too crazy going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did figure out why I was crashing but I was able to come up with a workaround. I was originally trying to make the view controller for the table cell which contained NSTextView be the delegate. I changed it so that the cell's view subclass itself was the delegate and all is well.

I don't get it but it works, so that's what matters.